# Smooth edges on a custom object

Tags: edges

I have a custom made object (no simple standard mesh, but nothing complex, see below) and lost a lot of time trying to make the edges smooth. 
I tried the bevel modifier, sub surf modifier and bevel by select certain edges (ctrl+B). None of them worked fast and reliable.

- Selecting them edge by edge (very time consuming) left me with problems where two different bevels where meeting.
- the bevel modifier did no work as expected every time
- sub surf modifier just created a very distorted mesh.

This is my mesh (viewed from different angles):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just want all the edges to be smooth. No big deal...I thought :)
I only succeeded on the front ones.

Comment: Did you enable smooth in shading?

Comment: I need this as a real object afterwards so shading does not help me. At least as I understand it. Thanks

Comment: @user413734, do you want to 3D print it ?

Comment: Yes, I just need these edges to be smooth and the rest of the object not distorted.

Comment: Try using Bevel modifier with angles enabled as a limit, then apply the subdivision surface modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to imagine the several angles your mesh will have to be bent.

It can be composed of an initial shape and 3 modifiers : mirror, simple deform and subsurface.

[image]
Here, there is a final curve : the "U" general shape.

But before that the mesh can be flat. Here the mesh before using the two final modifier (simple deform and subsurface) :

[image]

The main point is to use quad everywhere so that :

- Edges are in the good position to be bend to the "U"
- Subsurface modifier works well

Notice the selected line on the screen capture : it is here to preserve the outer edge and avoid the subsurf to deform it too much.

As you want to print it, you may want a "lot" of subdivision.

Here is the modifiers stack :

[image]

Here is the blend file [image]

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you share the blend ? What is the starting form you used ? A cube with rounded corners ? Did you choose a Mirror Object in the Mirror Modifier. Thanks.

Comment: Edited to add the file (at the end of the post)

Comment: Thank you very much. One last questions how did you add the line that protects the edge. Edge Loops won't work with me becuase it is not a straight line I think. Thanks again.

Comment: @user413734, if I remember well, a bevel, Ctrl+B and the some manual adjustments for the extremities